# Creating an NSPredicate based off of a SQL Query

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have the following SQL that I need turned into an NSPredicate:

```
SELECT * FROM accounts
WHERE deleted = NO AND inactive = N0
AND name LIKE 'Harry%'
ORDER BY accounts DESC, sales DESC;
```

Also instead of the like in SQL and NSPredicate, can I use BEGINSWITH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *atributeValue =@“Harry”;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@“deleted == %@ && inactive == %@ && name begindsWith %@ ”, @0,@0,atributeValue];

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor1 = [nssortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@“accounts”ascending : NO];

NSSortDescriptor *descriptor2 = [nssortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@“sales”ascending : NO];

NSArray *result = [all filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate]sortedArrayUsingDescriptors :[NSArray arrayEithObjects:descriptor1,descriptor2];
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

An NSPredicate corresponds to just the WHERE clause of a SQL query.  You could use `name = false and inactive = false and name like 'Harry*'`, or yes you could use `name BEGINSWITH 'Harry'` instead of the like.  Note that it uses glob-type wildcards of "?" and "*" instead of SQL wildcards.  Fuller documentation is available at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html .  The NSFetchRequest class would represent the rest of the clauses -- that specifies the entity to fetch (the FROM clause) and the sort descriptors (the ORDER BY clause) along with the predicate.